# Pre requisties for setting different Screen Resolution layouts in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android app. But I faced a problem for different screen resolution, images are overlapping in small size screen and looks fine in normal size screen. I tried layout-small xml for small screen size with small images in drawable-ldpi.But it doesn't work.Does layout-small is supported for API level 13 or below or any such specification?

Answer (score 0):

> Does layout-small is supported for API level 13 or below or any such specification?

`res/layout-small/` has been supported since API Level 1.

> I tried layout-small xml for small screen size with small images in drawable-ldpi.

`-ldpi` is for low-density screens. While *most* `-small` screens will also be `-ldpi`, not all will.

> But it doesn't work

Nobody can help you if you are unwilling to explain your problem in greater detail. "It doesn't work" is the same as going to your doctor, saying "I don't feel well", and expecting the doctor to cure you without any further information from you.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity."But it doesn't work" by this I mean I tried layout-small xml's for small screen resolution with small size images in drawable-ldpi but this didn't work. I still face the problem of overlapping images.